# How can I make parent div scale, based on number of children in html/css/bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Unfortunaelly question is too long to give me proper results on google or here, all I got is some scaling of svg elements.

What I wanted to do is make online shop, where parent contains results which are div boxes, and size of parent should be relative to number of children.

So lets say I have 14 children divs, 4 per row, than I can use starting min-height:768 px, but if there is lets say 200 children, than I need to increase height of container and containers parent by (200/4-4)*128px, because 4 rows are basic screen and other 46 won't fit in., how I do that dynamicaly, and based on screen resolution?

**Edit:** I tried to add some details:
[IMG of my current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fynxf.png) what I want to do atm is increase size of light gray box, its parent (white box) and its parent (almost transparent box) if there is too many red boxes, that leave bound of first container (light gray box)

Comment: A normal block element would increase the height per default. You need to give more input to get an answer for this.

Comment: I added block to its parent but parents of that parents are not increasing in size, what should I do?

Comment: So you want size of parent to scale based on the number of children in the tallest column? The size of the children is the default and generally considered more fitting. Not quite sure what (or why) you're trying to do.

Comment: I am really sorry for bad quality of my question, I will try to form it better: I have parent which has default height of 1000px. and it stays that big until people search for something and many results match search, than I want to make parent bigger. I don't want to scale parent based on number of children in tallest column, I just want to scale it by the number of children over all, while also having a big of padding inside parent, so that children dont touch corners of parent, I am really sorry If I am missing something basic I just couldnt find solution.

Comment: I believe [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) is what you need, as `min-height: 1000px`. It's hard to tell without having a [mcve] to look at.

Comment: I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put static height property to parent of parent of your node.

```
    overflow: scroll;
```

should work as far as i know.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I really feel stupid for forgetting this one, it really does nice job on pc. My main complain is that it kind of makes it messed up on mobile. Also, unrelated to this question, just for estetic, when I added scroll, it also added horizontal scroll arrow, even that its never wider than espected, and there is no need for scroll left/right, how do I remove it, if possible.

Comment: Make padding and boxsizing to be not wider than view-port-max width of device in use. It would be more like try your value that is going to work. it is easier to use bootstrap for this problem.
There might be need to reset everything up to clear default browser behavior on element that is making it go wider than necessary

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need js solution http://masonry.desandro.com/

Sometimes this i use

Comment: I feel like it would tkae some time to learn, and I am kind of in rush, sorry, maybe for next project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, in case anyone is like me trying to make some complex objects inside objects and than has problems positioning and scaling them all maybe you did something like I did.

Inside container I have positioned every object in middle by making it:
position: absolute; transform: translateX(-50%); and I did like this for like 10 objects, position absolute caused my child divs to leave arent instead of increasing its size, all that I should have done is just add padding of container 5%, because all children had width of 90%, and dont set position for children of containe, just manipulate them with paddings and margins.